# Replace specific junk characters from column in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I've an issue where one of the column loaded in a hive table contains junk character (`"~`) in a column suffixed with actual value (`ABC`). So the actual value that's visible for this column is (`ABC"~`).

This column can have either ABC (or any such string) or NULL. The table is huge and Update is not an option here.

I've thought of a solution of creating a temp table with this column containing either the string (`ABC`) or NULL, thereby want to remove this junk character (`"~`) completely while copying the data from original table to this temp table.

Any help on how I can remove this junk? I tried using regexp function, but no success. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why you want to replace. Since Hive is Schema on Read. You can create Hive Table with any hive serde(like opencsvserde) which provide option to escape sequence(here you can escape "~) during read. This will help to reduce a extensive IO which will happen during replace. Share the details of schema and few data records if possible.

Comment: How did you load the data? The problem sounds like it exists there

Answer (score 0):

I was not using regexp properly; my fault.

The data loaded initially in the table had the extra characters attached to a column's values. For Ex: If the column's actual value was `Adf452`, then the data contained in the cell was `Adf452"~`.

So I loaded the data to a temp table like this:

```
insert overwrite table tempTable select colA, colB, colC, regexp_replace(colC,"\"~",""), partitionedCol from origTable;
```

This simply loaded the data in tempTable without those junk characters.